# How to connect web dashboard with android application and send data

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, dashboard

How can I connect my web dashboard with an Android app? I want details on the dashboard of those people who create accounts using my app and add products in a mobile app using a web dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Use a common database server for both the website and android app. That way it will be easier to share data.